# Where can found php.ini file from Parallels Panel?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, hosting, parallels

I need to increase memory limit in php.ini for WordPress website. So need to edit php.ini file but where is it in Parallels Panel I can not find.

Comment: create a file name as user.ini in root directory and add these two into it max_file_uploads = 128M
memory_limit = 128M when you done rename it as .user.ini

Comment: I was follow your step but not working

Comment: Now showing "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 76 bytes) in /var/www/vhosts/privilege-card.co.uk/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/businessfinder2/ait-theme/@framework/libs/AitLess.inc on line 1666 "

Comment: replace with this  max_file_uploads = 2048M
memory_limit = 2048M
upload_max_filesize = 2048M
max_input_vars= 5000M
post_max_size=128M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be found which configuration file is used by PHP by using a script with the phpinfo(); function:

```
# cat /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/httpdocs/info.php
<?php phpinfo();?>
```

Open a page which contains this PHP code and review the " Configuration File (php.ini) Path ", " Scan this dir for additional .ini files " and " additional .ini files parsed " sections at the beginning of the page.

Since Parallels Plesk 10 it is possible to set up php.ini per-domain for each domain which is running PHP scripts as a CGI of FastCGI application. In this case it should be located in ${VHOST_DIR}//etc/ directory to be recognized by PHP interpreter.

there are other ways for wordpress you can check at http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-increase-the-maximum-file-upload-size-in-wordpress/

Comment: Actually I want to know from where I can find the php.ini file in Parallels Pane.